# I have lost 3kg in 5 days - is this bad?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, bodyweight-exercises, health

I have recently started eating healthy and going to the gym, nothing too crazy - just eating roughly 5000kJ a day and going to the gym 5 days a week for 60-90 minutes each day. I have been doing this for a few weeks, but only just started weighing myself this week. I weigh myself every morning, and was going to take the average at the end of the week, thinking my weight was going to go up & down.

I have noticed that in the last 5 days, I have lost 3kg - this seems like a lot, I am a 25yr old female and I weigh 64kg.

Comment: That's entirely plausible, especially if you're performing lots of cardio within that time or cardio-based weightlifting. Your calorie intake is about 1200 and your weight is about 140 lbs. As long as you have energy to continue your routine, you should be fine. The weight loss will reduce over time though, as your body fat level reduces.

Answer (score 2):

If this was 3 kg of fat, that would mean you just lost 3*7000 kcal or 87864 kj, this is obviously entirely unplausible. What does make sense however is that you just lost a bit of water and solids, which is common when you start eating more healthy.

Your weight will always fluctuate a bit, you will have a high and low limit for your weight, if you start writing down and ideally charting your weight, you will notice when you break new low limits and when your high limit seems to have been lowered as well. That will give you an idea of how fast you're actally losing weight.

This might been discouraging right now, but it's nice to know when you have pizza one night and suddenly add 2 kg (of water weight, carbs and salt bind water.)